# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.practice.projectbm.Model.User.getName()' on a null object reference

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, android-adapter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMOFp.png)I'm trying to get the data from firebase database which has child called EmailUsers which consists of name, email, bio etc. I want to display these items in my xml view. But I'm getting the error as mentioned in title.
Here is my ProfileFragment.java

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment
{

    ImageView back_button_to_feed, share, settings;
    private CircleImageView profile_photo;
    private int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private Uri imageUri;
    private TextView ques;
    private TextView followers;
    private TextView following;
    private Button editprof;
    private TextView username;
    private TextView bioo;
    private FirebaseUser fire;
    String profileId;

    public interface ProfileFragmentCallback
    {
        public void onSettingsClicks();
    }


    public static ProfileFragmentCallback profileFragmentCallback;
    public static ProfileFragment GetInstance(ProfileFragmentCallback callback)
    {
        profileFragmentCallback = callback;
        return new ProfileFragment();
    }

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;








    public ProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static ProfileFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

        }
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container, false);
        //Mapping
        back_button_to_feed = view.findViewById(R.id.back_arrow);
        profile_photo = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
        share = view.findViewById(R.id.share_profile);
        settings = view.findViewById(R.id.settings_in_profile);
        username = view.findViewById(R.id.account_username);
        bioo = view.findViewById(R.id.bio);
        followers = view.findViewById(R.id.followers);
        following = view.findViewById(R.id.following);
        editprof = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_details);
        fire = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        profileId = fire.getUid();


        //Mapping Ends


        //If user clicks on back button we'll take him to feed
        back_button_to_feed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                    getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        //If user clicks on back button we'll take him to feed Ends

        //If user clicks on share
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hey Check Out My Profile");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://youtube.com");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via"));
            }
        });
        //If user clicks on share Ends

        //If user clicks on settings
        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                profileFragmentCallback.onSettingsClicks();
            }
        });
        //If user clicks on settings Ends

        //for image selection
        profile_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //LOGIC FOR PROFILE PICTURE
                openImageChooser();
            }
        });
        //for image selection Ends

        userInfo();
        getFollowersAndFollowingCount();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment Ends


    }



    private void getFollowersAndFollowingCount()
    {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(profileId);
        ref.child("Followers").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull  DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {
                followers.setText(" " + snapshot.getChildrenCount());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull  DatabaseError error)
            {

            }
        });
        ref.child("Following").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull  DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {
                following.setText(" " + snapshot.getChildrenCount());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull  DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void userInfo()
    {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("EmailUsers").child(profileId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull  DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                username.setText(user.getName());
                bioo.setText(user.getBio());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull  DatabaseError error)
            {

            }
        });
    }


    void openImageChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }







}
```

Here is my User model class

```
public class User
{
private String name;
private String email;
private String bio;
private String Imageurl;
private String id;


public User()
{

}

public User(String name, String email, String bio, String imageurl, String id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.bio = bio;
    Imageurl = imageurl;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getBio() {
    return bio;
}

public void setBio(String bio) {
    this.bio = bio;
}

public String getImageurl() {
    return Imageurl;
}

public void setImageurl(String imageurl) {
    Imageurl = imageurl;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

Here is my UserAdapter

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder>
{

private Context mContext;
private List<User> mUsers;
private boolean isFragment;

private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

public UserAdapter(Context mContext, List<User> mUsers, boolean isFragment)
{
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mUsers = mUsers;
    this.isFragment = isFragment;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false);
    return new UserAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  UserAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    User user = mUsers.get(position);
    holder.followw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.uname.setText(user.getName());
    Picasso.get().load(user.getImageurl()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.imageProfile);

    isFollowed(user.getId(), holder.followw);

    if(user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()))
    {
        holder.followw.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    holder.followw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(holder.followw.getText().toString().equals("Follow"))
            {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("Following").child(user.getId()).setValue(true);


                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(user.getId()).child("Followers").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
            }
            else
            {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("Following").child(user.getId()).removeValue();


                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(user.getId()).child("Followers").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }

        }
    });
}

private void isFollowed(String id, Button followw)
{
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("Following");

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull  DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {
            if(snapshot.child(id).exists())
            {
                followw.setText("Following");
            }
            else
            {
                followw.setText("Follow");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull  DatabaseError error)
        {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return mUsers.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public CircleImageView imageProfile;
    public TextView uname;
    public Button followw;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        imageProfile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        uname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        followw = itemView.findViewById(R.id.follow);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **500 (five hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is right to set Override for your onClick method. Aren't you simply calling an existing method for a button you've created? Annotations are used when overwriting an implementation of a method of a superclass, but aren't you referring to a standard click event? Don't know if this will solve your problem. Have you tested the outcome of the variables you pass between your methods? Since there's a nullpointer error coming from calling upon the user object, I 'd start by looking over the more closely related subjects like useradapter.

In your useradapter class

```
System.out.println(view) //Check to see if this is what you were expecting

return new UserAdapter.ViewHolder(view);


System.out.println(holder)  //Check to see if this is what you were expecting

User user = mUsers.get(position);
holder.followw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
holder.uname.setText(user.getName());
```

Then trace instances that are related in your code like when u set up ur view, and do some more checking.

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container, false);
    //Mapping

    System.out.println(view) //another check

    back_button_to_feed = view.findViewById(R.id.back_arrow);
    profile_photo = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
    share = view.findViewById(R.id.share_profile);
    settings = view.findViewById(R.id.settings_in_profile);
    username = view.findViewById(R.id.account_username);
    bioo = view.findViewById(R.id.bio);
    followers = view.findViewById(R.id.followers);
    following = view.findViewById(R.id.following);
    editprof = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_details);
    fire = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    profileId = fire.getUid();
```

Good luck!